# Change property type in DataGrid style in the Paint function?

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid, compact-framework

I have a datagrid which maps out to an SQLDataAdapater, one of the rows is an integer which is an id that corresponds to a string.

What I'd like to do in the paint function is:

```
protected override void Paint( Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source, int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight )
  {
     int id = ( ( int )this.PropertyDescriptor.GetValue( source.List[ rowNum ] ) );

     int oldValue = id;
    this.PropertyDescriptor.SetValue( source.List[ rowNum ], "Some Text" );// m_textDataMapping[ id ] );
     base.Paint( g, bounds, source, rowNum, backBrush, foreBrush, alignToRight );
     this.PropertyDescriptor.SetValue( source.List[ rowNum ], oldValue );
}
```

I get an error on  this.PropertyDescriptor.SetValue about invalid argument exception which I assume it is because of type, if I set another integer it runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use the [PropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but its [PropertyType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.propertytype%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is readonly. So, if it is an integer, you can not write text to that value.

If you want to change a field to display some text, you will likely need to change the SQL used in your [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so that `rowNum` is displayed as text.

For example, instead of this SQL:

```
SELECT ID1
FROM Table1
```

You could use this version of SQL:

```
SELECT CAST(ID1 AS nVarChar(50)) AS 'ID1'
FROM Table1
```

Now, you can treat `rowNum` as a text field.

However, this does come with a price. Now, you are also going to have to convert values you read in from string values to integer values.